# Regular expression to find non-escaped characters

Tags: .net, regex

I need to find the hex characters with the format `_x[0-9A-F]{4}_` except when they're preceded by `_x005F` (using .Net)

I tried  `[^(_x005F)]_x[0-9A-F]{4}_` but it doesn't work because it would match `_x005F_` on the string `AA_x005F_x00FF_BB` (in this case I don't want it to match anything).

Comment: @errorstacks, please be careful when you edit.  You introduced some underscores that originally weren't there.

Comment: @detunized: I think the OP intended those underscores to be there.

Comment: @detunized oops sorry i have just got update...

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks for the heads up. It got posted twice by mistake. I already flagged the other one for the mods to take a look.

Comment: @MarkByers, not in his original version.  Check edits.

Comment: @detunized: I see underscores in the source of the original version too (though it shows up as italicized text in the formatted version).

Comment: @detunized its look like same now ...

Comment: @MarkByers, ok that explains it =)

Comment: What do you want to match if the string is "AA_x005F_x005F_x00FF_BB"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it very clear, but you seem to have two very similar requirements:

- Don't match if the *previous* characters are `x005F`.
- Don't match if the *current* characters are `x005F`.

Try this:

```
"(?<!_x005F)_x(?!005F)[0-9A-F]{4}_"
```

Full example:

```
string s = "AA_x0042_x005F_x00FF_x0043_BB";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, "(?<!_x005F)_x(?!005F)[0-9A-F]{4}_"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
_x0042_
_x0043_
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/wF1Xd)

Comment: You seem to be assuming `_x005F_` itself always has to be escaped (i.e. `_x005F_x005F_`), just like literal backslashes in string literals do.  But this syntax seems to allow for `_x005F_` to stand alone.

Comment: Anyway, in your sample string I think it should match `_x0042_` and `_x00FF_`.  `_x005F` is not an escape character because the underscore is part of `_x0042_`, and `_x0043_` is not a hex character because the first `_` belongs to `_x00FF_`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *negative lookbehind*.  Like this:

```
(?<!_x005F)_x[0-9A-F]{4}_
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!pattern)
```

for example:

```
(?<!_x005F)x[0-9A-F]{4}_
```

**Edit** - corrected answer

Comment: Someone edited the question while I was posting :) Add or remove underscores as needed :)

Comment: This is not going to work.  You need to use negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do with `[^(_x005F)]` should be a negative lookbehind: `(?<!_x005F)`.  But it doesn't really work, for the reason Mark Byers pointed out: it incorrectly matches the leading `_x005F_` in escaped hex sequences like `_x005F_x00FF_`.

However, I don't Mark's solution with the added negative lookahead works either;  malformed text seems to throw it out of sync, as I described in my comment to his answer.  I believe the only sure way to stay in sync with the hex/escape sequences is to match all the text *between* the unescaped hex sequences too, and use a capturing groups to extract the part you want.  This regex works for me:

```
\G(?>(?>(?:(?!_x[0-9A-F]{4}_).)+|_x005F_x[0-9A-F]{4}_)*)(_x[0-9A-F]{4}_)
```

I know that looks awful, but bear with me. :D  Here's the breakdown:

- `\G` anchors the match to the beginning of the string on the first iteration, and to the position where the last match ended thereafter.
- `(?:(?!_x[0-9A-F]{4}_).)+` repeatedly consumes any character, *unless* the lookahead determines that it's the first character of hex sequence.
- `_x005F_x[0-9A-F]{4}_` consumes an escaped hex sequence.
- `(?>(?:(?!_x[0-9A-F]{4}_).)+|_x005F_x[0-9A-F]{4}_)*` repeats those alternatives as many times as possible.  When it quits, the next thing has to be the end of the string or an unescaped hex sequence, which will be captured in group #1 by...
- `(_x[0-9A-F]{4}_)`

And here's an [online demo](http://ideone.com/JCE2x), the output of which is:

```
abc_x0011_def_x005F__x0022_ghi_x005F_x0033_jkl_x0042_x005F_x00FF_x0043_mno
   ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^         

_x0011_
_x005F_
_x0022_
_x0042_
_x00FF_
```

The first `_x005F_` doesn't escape the following `_x0022_` because of the trailing underscore. I don't know if it's okay to have it stand alone like that, but I don't see why it shouldn't be.  The next `_x005F` *does* escape the `_x0033_`.

The rest of the sample demonstrates what I think is wrong with Mark's solution.  But it could be me that has it wrong; I don't know the full syntax of the language you're working on.